# Why is 'go to definition' not working in Spyder?

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I have installed Python using anaconda and I am using the Spyder editor on Mac. I wanna be able to access the function definitions when I right click on a python built in function and click go to definition. Right now I get nothing.How do I do this? Am I missing the libraries or there is some settings? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when I right click on a python built in function

Those are written in C. Spyder has no Python source code to jump to. It would need access to the C source code and a way to automatically determine where in the C the relevant implementation is, and I don't think it has either of those things.

You'll have to find them in the C source code repository, probably in [`Python/bltinmodule.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.0/Python/bltinmodule.c) or under [`Objects`](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/v3.7.0/Objects)